# Excel formula into VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

How to implement this formula `=SUMPRODUCT(--(LEN(A1:A100)>0))` in VBA. I got Type Mismatch error.

This is what I did in vba, but not working:

```
WorksheetFunction.SumProduct(--(Len(Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A100")) > 0))
```

Comment: Show us the code that cause the error??

Comment: @RaymondWu Question edited.

Comment: Do you need the formula in the cell or just the result? You could do `range.Formula = "=SUMPRODUCT(--(LEN(A1:A100)>0))"`

Answer (score 1):

Try to use:

```
Evaluate("=SUMPRODUCT(--(LEN(Sheet1!A1:A100)>0))")
```

If you want to calculate only non-empty cells, you can use:

```
WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A100"))
```